# Variable substitution into a sed script

Tags: bash, sed

After running this code

```
#!/bin/bash
rm -f myfile myfile-individual
echo "Greetings, foobar!" > myfile
MYSTRING="Jack"
cat myfile | sed 's:foobar:$MYSTRING:' > myfile-individual
```

we end up with

```
Greetings, $MYSTRING!
```

in myfile-individual.

What should be the (sed/bash) script for the output to be instead

```
Greetings, Jack!
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change the single quotes to double quotes.  And drop the cat (UUoC):

```
sed "s:foobar:$MYSTRING:" myfile > myfile-individual
```

From the manpage for bash:

```
   Enclosing characters in single quotes preserves the  literal  value  of
   each character within the quotes.  A single quote may not occur between
   single quotes, even when preceded by a backslash.

   Enclosing characters in double quotes preserves the  literal  value  of
   all  characters  within the quotes, with the exception of $, `, \, and,
   when history expansion is enabled, !.  The characters $  and  `  retain
   their  special meaning within double quotes.  The backslash retains its
   special meaning only when followed by one of the following  characters:
   $,  `,  ", \, or <newline>.  A double quote may be quoted within double
   quotes by preceding it with a backslash.  If enabled, history expansion
   will  be  performed  unless an !  appearing in double quotes is escaped
   using a backslash.  The backslash preceding the !  is not removed.
```

Comment: Thanks. I found that 's:foobar:'$MYSTRING':' will also work, but the double quotes make the code more legible. Quick sequel: is it possible for sed to substitute in-place (without saving into a new file)?

Comment: Yes, look at the `-i` option in sed.

Comment: Instead of `sed -i` you should look into `ed` as well.  `sed -i` breaks links and is not very portable but if you don't have to worry about either, then it may be fine.

Comment: @Calaf: .. regarding what you said about  `'s:foobar:'$MYSTRING':'` will also work.. It won't work if `$MYSTRING` contains a sequence of whitespace; which the shell will collapse into a single space... However `'s:foobar:'"$MYSTRING"':'` will work in that case.

Answer (score -1):

```
sed -i 's|foobar|$MYSTRING' myfile-individual
```

This will do the substitution as well as write it in file