# Adding a JSON snippet to the second last line

Tags: sed, json

I would like to add the following JSON snippet (with the indentation and all) to another JSON file(main.json) on the second to the last line.

**JSON snippet to be added**

```
"extendedProperties": {
        "AppID": {
          "values": [
            "12345"
          ]
        }
```

**Method**

1. added the snippet to a variable e,g, snippet=`cat toAddintoConnection.txt`
2. tested `echo "$snippet"` and it listed exactly (with the indentation)
3. `sed '$i"$snippet"' main.json` - the result is that it printed `"$snippet"` literally at the 2nd last line.

Your guidance is truly appreciated. Thank you.
Prakash

Comment: Sure, you put the variable inside single quotes, which prevents variable expansion. Please also tell us what is `$i`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Variable substitution into a sed script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/35819/variable-substitution-into-a-sed-script)

Comment: you mean like this sed '$i'$snippet'' main.json ? I tried but it didn't work as well. and the $i is something I found on another side . just copied

Comment: Indentation does not affect JSON documents, nor does the ordering of keys.

Answer (score 2):

Note that the indentation, newlines, and other whitespaces between keys and values are not important in JSON documents.  Also, the ordering of keys does not matter.

Using `jq`, adding the extra top-level key and its value from the command line:

```bash
jq '.extendedProperties = { AppID: { values: [ "12345" ] } }' main.json
```

With the `AppID` string taken from a shell variable:

```bash
id=12345

jq --arg AppID "$id" '.extendedProperties = { AppID: { values: [ $AppID ] } }' main.json
```

To add the data from a file, assuming that `toAddintoConnection.txt` is a properly formatted JSON document to be added, such as

```json
{
  "extendedProperties": {
    "AppID": {
      "values": [
        "12345"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

or, equivalently,

```json
{"extendedProperties":{"AppID":{"values":["12345"]}}}
```

... you may add this to the pre-existing JSON document `main.json` like so:

```bash
jq -s 'add' main.json toAddintoConnection.txt
```

Comment: this works perfectly well! thank you all.

Comment: @PrakashSundra Good! If this solves your issue, please consider [accepting the answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). Accepting an answer marks the issue as resolved.